# Select ClaimsIdentity directly via Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have a user table with following columns:

- Id : Guid
- Name: string
- IsAdmin: bool

Now I want to create a select using EF Core with a `ClaimsIdentity` result:

```cs
public ClaimsIdentity? GetIdentity(string email, string password)
{
   return _context.Users
       .Where(user => user.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()))
       .Where(user => user.Password.Equals(password))
       .Select(user => new ClaimsIdentity(
           new Claim("id", user.Id.ToString()),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, UserRole.ADMIN.ToString())
       ))
       .SingleOrDefault();
```

But currently I don't know if the dynamic claims-list is possible respectively how I can archive that. The claim "Admin" should only be in the claims-list if the user is administrator (`IsAdmin = true`).

Or do I need a temporary class/DTO (e.g. `UserIdentity`) to select the data? But in that case, can I then have a dynamic list of roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this for your use case

```
public ClaimsIdentity? GetIdentity(string email, string password)
             {
            return _context.Users
                .Where(user => user.Email.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower()))
                .Where(user => user.Password.Equals(password))
                .Select(user =>
                {
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                    new Claim("id", user.Id.ToString())
                    );
                    if (UserRole.ADMIN == true)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, UserRole.ADMIN.ToString()))
                    }
                    return identity;
                })
                .SingleOrDefault();
            }
```